# How can I compile a hybrid (asm, C++) source code into a 32-bit program?

Tags: c++, assembly, makefile, cygwin

I am using **Cygwin 32-bit** under Win7 in a 64-bit machine.

The following program

makefile:

```
runme:  main.cpp    asm.o
        g++ main.cpp    asm.o   -o  executable

asm.o:  asm.asm
        nasm    -f  elf     asm.asm     -o  asm.o
```

asm.asm:

```
section .data
section .bss
section .text
    global GetValueFromASM

GetValueFromASM:
    mov eax, 9
    ret
```

main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

extern "C" int GetValueFromASM();

int main()
{
    cout<<"GetValueFromASM() returned = "<<GetValueFromASM()<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

is giving me the following error:

```
$ make
nasm    -f      elf             asm.asm         -o      asm.o
g++     main.cpp        asm.o   -o      executable
/tmp/cc3F1pPh.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x26): undefined reference to `GetValueFromASM'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [makefile:2: runme] Error 1
```

I am not understanding why this error is being generated.

How can I get rid of this issue?

Comment: With Cygwin you have to prepend your external assembly function names with an `_`. in the assembly file. Change `global GetValueFromASM` to `global _GetValueFromASM` and the label `GetValueFromASM:` to `_GetValueFromASM:`

Comment: I think you made that comment just before I answered the question :). It's funny how Windows works, isn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to prefix your symbols with `_`, as is customary in Windows/Cygwin:

```
section .data
section .bss
section .text
    global _GetValueFromASM

_GetValueFromASM:
    mov eax, 9
    ret
```

The rest of your code should work fine.

An alternative would be to compile with `-fno-leading-underscore`. However, this may break linking with other (Cygwin system) libraries. I suggest using the first option if portability to other platforms does not matter to you.

Quoting from the GNU Online Docs:

> `-fleading-underscore`
>
> This option and its counterpart, `-fno-leading-underscore`, forcibly change the way C symbols are represented in the object file. One use is to help link with legacy assembly code.
>
> **Warning:** the `-fleading-underscore` switch causes GCC to generate code that is not binary compatible with code generated without that switch. Use it to conform to a non-default application binary interface. Not all targets provide complete support for this switch.

Comment: Another option with g++ is doing `extern "C" int GetValueFromASM() asm ("GetValueFromASM");` The label in the ASM part will be the label that will be resolved (so one without the underscore). Then the assembly code doesn't change. It isn't my preference, just pointing out the option.

Comment: Didn't know you could do that. Is that also possible in C without the `extern "C"` part?

Comment: If using _C_, you drop the `extern C` and it will work. This is a G++/GCC extension and not part of the _C_ standard. This is discussed in the [GCC documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.4.0/gcc/Asm-Labels.html#Asm-Labels) under _ASM Labels_